# Jquery for loop on click mistake

Tags: jquery

First of all I do not have HTML control. 
I have mistake in the for loop somewhere as if I do just for one id it works fine.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 73; i++) {
  $("#a" + i).click(function() {
    if ($("#a" + i).hasClass("green")) {
      $("#Q15v2_" + i).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $("#Q15v2_" + i).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: why click event in for loop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: what is your requirement ?

Comment: I would like to write this code below in the for loop as there is 72 elements.                                                                                  $("#a1").click(function(){
    if($("#a1").hasClass("green")){
   
     $("#Q15v2_1").prop('checked', true);
    
    } else{
     $("#Q15v2_1").prop('checked', false);
    
    }
  
 
   });

Comment: what is #a element type ?

Comment: Don't make 72 click bindings

Comment: #a paragraph word id

Comment: Please provide HTML, i am almost sure there is easier way to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and let me know :
check this https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/g1x7rh25/

```
$("p[id^=a").click(function() {   // paragraph id start with 'a'
    var len = $(this).prop('id').length;    // calculate id length
    var i = $(this).prop('id').substr(1,len);  // remove 'a' from id to get number
    if ($(this).hasClass("green")) {
        $("#Q15v2_" + i).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#Q15v2_" + i).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Minor tweak: `if ($("#a" + i).hasClass("green")) {` can be `if ($(this).hasClass("green")) {`

Comment: thanks for correction, I copy pasted @
Zygimantas Kairys's code  also no need of `else` until we manually checks it (p with no `green` class)

Comment: You can go to the nth degree with improving this - that one seemed the most beneficial without changing too much of the original code.

Comment: shantaram_t, I think I got it working just I have changed "p[id^=a" to '[id*="a"]'